# phpseclib rsa key generation the exponent is same

Tags: php, phpseclib

in 
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net the exponent generating is the same.. every time when the key is generated.. and this is unable to decrypt at the java(android) side..

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>AKoYq6Q7UN7vOFmPr4fSq2NORXHBMKm8p7h4JnQU+quLRxvYll9cn8OBhIXq9SnCYkbzBVBkqN4ZyMM4vlSWy66wWdwLNYFDtEo1RJ6yZBExIaRVvX/eP6yRnpS1b7m7T2Uc2yPq1DnWzVI+sIGR51s1/ROnQZswkPJHh71PThln</Modulus>
  <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
  <P>AN4DDp+IhBca6QEjh4xlm3iexzLajXYrJid6vdWmh4T42nar5nem8Ax39o3ND9b1Zoj41F9zFQmuZ8/AgabreKU=</P>
  <Q>AMQi+R0G9m0K+AcqK3DFpv4RD9jGc0Tle98heNYT7EQvZuuiq4XjvRz0ybqN//bOafrKhsTpRS9DQ7eEpKLI4Bs=</Q>
  <DP>FklyR1uZ/wPJjj611cdBcztlPdqoxssQGnh85BzCj/u3WqBpE2vjvyyvyI5kX6zk7S0ljKtt2jny2+00VsBerQ==</DP>
  <DQ>AJGC1Mg5Oydo5NwD6BiROrPxGo2bpTbu/fhrT8ebHkTz2eplU9VQQSQzY1oZMVX8i1m5WUTLPz2yLJIBQVdXqhM=</DQ>
  <InverseQ>EaiK5KhKNp9SFXuLVwQalvzyHk0FhnNZcZnfuwnlCxb6wnKg117fEfy91eHNTt5PzYPpf+xzD1FnP7/qsIninQ==</InverseQ>
  <D>Fijko56+qGyN8M0RVyaRAXz++xTqHBLh3tx4VgMtrQ+WEgCjhoTwo23KMBAuJGSYnRmoBZM3lMfTKevIkAidPExvYCdm5dYq3XToLkkLv5L2pIIVOFMDG+KESnAFV7l2c+cnzRMW0+b6f8mR1CJzZuxVLL6Q02fvLi55/mbSYxE=</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Answer (score 2):

AQAB is the base64 encoded version of 65537, which is pretty common for exponents.  In fact, usually, the public exponent is hard-coded.  It's intended to be small so that encryption is fast.  The private exponent is usually much larger and that one can be pretty much anything.

The following URL elaborates:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537_(number)#Applications

As for Android not accepting the key...  my guess would be that it just doesn't support that format.  I dunno...  maybe try phpseclib's default output format?  ie. a PEM encoded RSA private key?